# CopyOnWriteLinkedList Implementation for Java

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there a CopyOnWriteLinkedList which is similar to CopyOnWriteArrayList? I searched it on the web but found none. Is there an alternative one that provides this functionality?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I am curious why CopyOnWriteArrayList is not sufficient.  Do you need the Deque interface?

Comment: @ditkin yes! I phrased it wrongly! sorry

Comment: @SreeAurovindh: why couldn't you use [`ConcurrentLinkedDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html)?

Comment: Thanks @LouisWasserman .. This is what I searching for.

Answer (score 2):

As Louis Wasserman suggested it would be advisable to use a [`ConcurrentLinkedDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html) for a concurrent Deque operation.